# pymongo huge collection return with list

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

You know that there is no join in mongodb, So I execute likes join query like this.

```
users = user_collection.find({"region": "US", `and some condition here`}, projection={"user_id": 1"})
user_list = [
    user['user_id']
    for user in users
]
posts = post_collection.find({"user_id": {"$in": user_list}, `and some condition here`)
```

(To avoid bring unnecessary field, also used `projection` option in `find()`)

**Collection and list size**

users = 2000000

user_list = 100000

posts = 2000000

When I execute query, it takes almost 4 seconds.

Among them, make `user_list` takes almost 3 seconds.

**Question**

1. How can I make a result to list only contains `user_id` efficiently?
2. Any way to improve performance here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that the fields you query on are properly indexed. If it's already done, you can try this:

#### 1. use distinct()

you could use [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) to get the `user_list` in one single query:

something like this:

```
user_list = user_collection.distinct("user_id", {"region": "US", ...})
```

#### 2. Aggregation with a $lookup

second option is to retrieve the posts in a single query by performing a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) from the `user_collection`:

```
user_collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {"region": "US", ...}
  }, 
  {
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "post_collection",
        "localField": "user_id",
        "foreignField": "user_id",
        "as": "post"
    }
  }, 
  ...
])
```

and then filter the posts with a [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and a [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage

Comment: `distinct()` more faster than `find()` with projection option?

Comment: @Hide `distinct()` will return only an array of size **n**, whereas `find()` will return **n** documents, that you have to convert in a single array so yes, `distinct()` should be faster

Comment: Ok. But I think, there is some mistakes in modeling. Any good reference for modeling that perform likes join query in mongodb?